# Photoswipe add new button googlemap external link

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to add a link to google map inside Photoswipe, but 
the link does not work.

```
<div class='Image_Wrapper'> 
        <a href='photo/1.jpg' data-size='786x772' data-med='photo/1.jpg' data-med-size='393x386' data-author='wer' class='galleryitem'>
          <img src='photo/1.jpg' alt='xxx  img: 1.jpg' />
            <figcaption class="img-title">
                <figure>
                    <h5>xxxx</h5>
                </figure>
             </figcaption>
        </a>
    <div style="background-color:gold;position:relative;width:100%;height:10%;top:0;z-index:1000;"><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=47.4074777777778,8.57738888888889&amp;z=3" target="blank">map</a></div>               
</div>
```